# .getScript() callback for multiple usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, promise

If I have 2 JS files like `a.js` and `b.js`

**a.js**

```
$.getScript('some.js',function(){
   //Call some function in some.js
});
```

In file **b.js**, I will call function some **some.js**, but how to know that **some.js** is loaded ?

Can I do something like.. (in **b.js**)

```
SomejsIsLoaded.then(function(){
   //Call some function in some.js
});
```

`.then()` `.promise()` ?

Comment: How are a.js and b.js loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getScript()` returns a jqXHR promise, which can be assigned for later use.

You could write ...

```
var somejsPromise = $.getScript('some.js', function() {
    //Call some function in some.js
});
```

... but it's better not to use the global namespace, so you could use the jQuery namespace :

```
$.somejsPromise = $.getScript('some.js', function() {
    //Call some function in some.js
});
```

In case the script 'some.js' doesn't load, you should also include some error handling. At the very least, log the error :

```
$.somejsPromise = $.getScript('some.js', function() {
    //Call some function in some.js
}).then(null, function(error) {
    console.log('getScript(some.js)', error);
});
```

Thereafter, the only safe way to run a script delivered in "some.js", is to use the assigned promise's `.then()` method :

```
$.somejsPromise.then(function() {
    //Call some function in some.js
}, function() {
    //handle the case that some.js fails to load.
});
```

If some.js has loaded, the callback will run immediately.

If some.js is not yet loaded, the callback will be queued, and will run if/when some.js loads.

If some.js has failed (or will fail), then the error handler will run.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether your `some.js` exists or not by checking the function in `some.js` exists or not

```
if (typeof sumefunction!= 'undefined') {
        //your code
    }
```

**Update:** 
You should place this check in the .`ready()` function of your `DOM` and if this check negates then you can manually load the script in your ready function

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = your script location;
head.appendChild(script);
```

or you can go on with `getScript()` or  with the jQuery [**.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function as

```
$('script').load(function () { });
```

Comment: If not ? how to do run `somefunction`

Comment: Ok m updating the answer